# CMIS on SharePoint Online / Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, cmis

How to access a SharePoint Online server via [CMIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services)?

The URL to the server is https://xyz.sharepoint.com but apparently the following CMIS URLs do not work:

```
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/cmis/soap/RepositoryService.svc
```

[This Microsoft document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj945829.aspx) says *"CMIS is not supported in SharePoint Online"* but I am not sure the information is up-to-date. By the way, I am OK with third-party add-ons.

Is there any trick or third-party add-on/gateway or similar that would enable us to access SharePoint Online via CMIS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it seems that [CMIS was half-implemented in Office365, but Microsoft voluntarily disabled it](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/77234.aspx#429643) (*URL broken after Microsoft reorganized their forums*).

CMIS is a protocol for interoperability, and it seems like Microsoft wants to prevent interoperability for Office365, presumably to prevent locked-in customers from migrating to more open solutions like Alfresco.

Companies who want CMIS interoperability should stay away from Office365 and install SharePoint on-premise.

I asked Microsoft to implement CMIS in all SharePoint products, and it became the [**highest-voted idea** on UserVoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/14691261-implement-cmis-for-real). Facing that, Microsoft **deleted it**, showing that they still consider [vendor lock-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in) as a feature rather than a bug. Let's not loose hope that Microsoft will one day become a bit more open, so please [vote for the re-created idea](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/10928106-enable-support-for-content-management-interoperabi).

Comment: The uservoice link has been deleted, but I found a new one [here](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/10928106-enable-support-for-content-management-interoperabi). Please vote for this if you need it, We are using a IBM tool that would go really well with this interoperability.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Deepak I added your link to the answer :-)